# SQL querying two sources

Tags: sql

I have a View and Table as example below

**Table1**

```
+---------+------+
| Country | City |
+---------+------+
| UK      | LDN  |
| US      | NEY  |
| US      | LAX  |
+---------+------+
```

**View1**

```
+---------+---------+-------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Site  |
+---------+---------+-------+
| Test    | Test2   | UKLDN |
| Test    | Test2   | USNEY |
| Test    | Test2   | USLAX |
| Test    | Test2   | PELMA |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

The result i'm trying to achieve is show all rows from **View1**, that have a `View1.Site` column matching `Table1.Country` and `Table1.City`. My confusion is how do to it as i'm not an sql person but more C# etc.

The resulting data I want to create is below. I don't know if I can do this solely from View1 or what functions to use.

**Result**

```
+---------+---------+-------+---------------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Site  | ExistInTable1 |
+---------+---------+-------+---------------+
| Test    | Test2   | UKLDN | Y             |
| Test    | Test2   | USNEY | Y             |
| Test    | Test2   | USLAX | Y             |
| Test    | Test2   | PELMA | N             |
+---------+---------+-------+---------------+
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post what your've tried so far. If you have not tried to write the SQL yet, it is going to be a simple select * from a left join b on a.field1 = b.field1 and a.field2 = b.field2. It's doubtful that the column site in your view1, would match both the table1 country and table1 city, so which fields need to match?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
SELECT V.*, CASE WHEN T.Country IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END ExistInTable1 FROM View1 V
LEFT JOIN Table1 T ON V.Site = (T.Country + T.City)
```

Comment: Merhaba Serkan, I have just build the SQL Select and was posting here and saw yours. It is interesting that I have the same query even for the alias, joins, etc :)

Comment: Actually, this kind of short queries doesn't have many alternatives. But equal query even same aliases interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a `LEFT JOIN` with your table and then check if it matches or not with the info from the view, like this:

```
SELECT
    VW.Column1
    ,VW.Column2
    ,VW.Site
    ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(T.country, T.city) IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS ExistInTable1
FROM View1 VW
LEFT JOIN Table1 T
    ON VW.site = CONCAT(T.country, T.City)
```

The `LEFT JOIN` keyword returns all records from the left table (`View1`), and the matched records from the right table (`Table1`). The result is `NULL` from the right side, if there is no match.(check done with the `CASE` statement)

You can test it [**Here**](http://rextester.com/ZHUS4920) as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is T-SQL, but the format should be very similar for most other flavors of SQL.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9fdb6cb/3)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (Country varchar(5),City varchar(5)) ;
INSERT INTO Table1 (Country,City)
VALUES ( 'UK','LDN'),('US','NEY'),('US','LAX')
;
CREATE TABLE View1 (Column1 varchar(10), Column2 varchar(10), Site varchar(10)) ;
INSERT INTO View1 (Column1,Column2,Site)
VALUES ('Test','Test2','UKLDN')
  , ('Test','Test2','USNEY')
  , ('Test','Test2','USLAX')
  , ('Test','Test2','PELMA') 
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT v.Column1, v.Column2
  , CASE WHEN LEN(COALESCE(t.Country,t.City)) > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS ExistsInTable1
FROM View1 v
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 t ON v.Site = (t.Country+t.City)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9fdb6cb/3/0)**:

```
| Column1 | Column2 | ExistsInTable1 |
|---------|---------|----------------|
|    Test |   Test2 |              Y |
|    Test |   Test2 |              Y |
|    Test |   Test2 |              Y |
|    Test |   Test2 |              N |
```